# How to start JHiccup programmatically?

Tags: java, performance

[JHiccup docs](https://github.com/giltene/jHiccup) recommends to start JHiccup with 1) javaagent, 2) injecting with process-id, or 3) starting it with a wrapper command.

Is it possible/recommended to start JHiccup in the host application with a simple Java-API call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with just one line of code:

```
    org.jhiccup.HiccupMeter.commonMain(args, false);
```

`args` is `String[]` array of the same arguments you would pass to javaagent or to the wrapper command.

Actually, all recommended ways to start jHiccup end up with the same call to `HiccupMeter.commonMain`. You may see this in the source code:

- [`premain`](https://github.com/giltene/jHiccup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jhiccup/HiccupMeter.java#L730) method of javaagent;
- [`agentmain`](https://github.com/giltene/jHiccup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jhiccup/HiccupMeter.java#L721) for dynamic attach;
- [`main`](https://github.com/giltene/jHiccup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jhiccup/HiccupMeter.java#L734) method of a wrapper program.